# How to (pre)start xamlx workflow service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, iis-7.5, xamlx, wcf-routing

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433670/wf4-workflow-versioning-using-workflowservicehost).

I have a xamlx workflow service that loads part of its definition from a database when it runs (using [ActivityXamlServices.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370926(VS.100).aspx)). Reason for this is that I need versioning, see the related question. I'll use WCF routing to direct calls to the right service.

The part that I load dynamically contains a [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.receive(VS.100).aspx) activity. However, this activity is 'invisible' as long as the workflow doesn't start because the part of the workflow I load from the database is only loaded when the workflow starts. So from the outside it appears as if there is no `Receive` activity in the workflow.

Apart from not being able to generate a contract for the workflow service, I can't call the service either. My first attempt was to do a soap call with the right contract on the workflow service. However, the runtime doesn't automagically activate my workflow in that case. So the question is, how do I start a workflow that is hosted inside IIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively new module for IIS 7.5 called Application Warmup. This is a configurable tool that allows IIS to start up your application w/ varying degree's of configurablity. I suggest checking out these two links:

http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationWarmUp

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/688/using-the-iis-application-warm-up-module/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server AppFabric includes an Auto Start feature that will help.

Check out [How to create a WF4 WorkflowServiceHostFactory for AppFabric Auto-Start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/04/27/how-to-create-a-wf4-workflowservicehostfactory-for-appfabric-auto-start.aspx)

I also have a sample that shows how to load XAMLX from a database with a Virtual Path Provider at 
[Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4) - Workflow Service Repository Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-8697594e)