# Resuming workflow after workflow definition has changed in .NET 4

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

In Workflow Foundation 4, what happens if I resume a persisted workflow, and in the meantime the workflow definition (e.g., the xaml file) for that workflow instance has changed?

Will I get an error, will it resume with the old definition, or will it resume with the new definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will generate an error. The only way to accomplish this now in WF4 is to store the old definition (XAML) somewhere and resume with that definition.

Microsoft is working on a workflow versioning implementation ([announced at PDC'10](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/3b87c17b-a218-40d3-984f-78a012331dee/2490)) but I'm not sure when that will be relased.

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064518/loading-persisted-workflow-after-workflowdefinition-has-changed-in-wf4) that may help you a little further.